h:inputFile on WildFly 32.0.1 throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.<init>() during restore view
I currently have a JSF application running on Wildfly 32.0.1 with Java 21, Mojarra 4.0.7 and Omnifaces 4.4.1.
Some of the pages allow the user to upload a file.
As long as there are no input validation errors, everything works as it should. The problem occurs when the user forgets to enter a required value and the input file has already been uploaded. In this case, the following exception is thrown:
11:20:58,866 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-9) UT005023: Exception handling request to /mywebapp/test/attachmentTest.xhtml: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:709)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.4.2.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:44)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@32.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1421)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.13.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.15.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:129)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.restoreState(ComponentStateHelper.java:321)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1232)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIOutput.restoreState(UIOutput.java:235)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIInput.restoreState(UIInput.java:1284)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.lambda$restoreView$1(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:357)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:125)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1266)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1278)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1278)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1278)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:346)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:90)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:258)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at deployment.myapp.ear.mywebapp.war//org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.restoreView(OmniViewHandler.java:128)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:162)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:96)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:131)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:719)
        at jakarta.faces.impl@4.0.7//jakarta.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:127)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3761)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:706)
        ... 70 more

I already tried using the o:inputFile from Omnifaces, but the behaviour is the same.
Page Bean
package com.test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Part;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AttachmentTest implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String description;

    private Part uploadedFile;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Part getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(Part uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        // do something with uploaded file;
        return "attachmentTest";
    }

}


View
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
        xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets"
        xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
        xmlns:a="jakarta.faces.passthrough">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <h:inputText id="description" value="#{attachmentTest.description}" required="true" requiredMessage="Required value"/>
                <h:message for="description"/>
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <label for="uploadedFile">Attachment</label>
                <h:inputFile id="uploadedFile" value="#{attachmentTest.uploadedFile}"/>
                <h:message for="uploadedFile"/>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <h:commandButton action="#{attachmentTest.doSomething}" value="Do Something"/>
            </div>
            
        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>

Scenario

User uploads file on form and does not enter description (required input)
Form validation fails because a required value was not set
User enters description
User uploads file
User submits form
Exception is thrown

Is there a way around this problem?
Is this a bug or am I missing something here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

This is in the end probably a bug in Mojarra. The HtmlInputFile#resetValue() should have been invoked during state saving but this is not happening. I don't have time to analyze and explain it right now but you should be able to work around it by adding transient="true" to the <h:inputFile>.

In fact, adding transient="true" seems  to fix the problem, although I'm not quite sure of the downside of adding this parameter. Anyway, thank you so much, @BalusC

It means it's not saved in view state. The only downside is that e.g. rendered/disabled/readonly which are programmatically manipulated won't be saved as well. But that shouldn't be a problem if you just bind these to a bean property like so disabled="#{bean.disabled}" as it will simply re-fetch from bean.
